# HTML5 presentations — what are they, what's the technology?

Tags: html, presentation

What are HTML5 presentations exactly... and what is the technology that they rely on?

Is it just plain CSS + AJAX? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Simply HTML4.01, CSS2.1 and JS or HTML5, CSS3 and bit of SVG, it's not that important. A long document is displayed screen by screen (page by page) to `presentation` and/or `screen` CSS media fullscreen or fullwidth and can be manipulated with mouse and keyboard (arrows, page up and down, etc). And as for SO, this type of question is too open and will likely cause debates, not straight to thepoint programming-related answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An HTML5 presentation system is just a presentation framework written with HTML5 technologies. For example, some presentation systems: http://www.sitepoint.com/5-free-html5-presentation-systems/.

Because presentation slides are dynamic, frameworks are necessarily written in Javascript and CSS.

Basically, it's just the same as all other client-side frameworks built on top of Javascript and CSS. The only difference is the purpose that it is designed for. Where other frameworks are made for dynamic client-side web applications, HTML5 presentation systems are frameworks designed for ... presentations.